# Put Back from trash from Terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, trash

I sent a lot of files and directories from an external hard drive into the trash by mistake. All those files and directories had the same grandfather directory but not the same father directory. I can put back each item individually but can't put back when I select several items that are not sister files/directory. Note that no path has been changed since I deleted all those files and directories. Anyway, I am thinking about using Bash.

Is there a `putback` command in bash?

Comment: It is probably too late now, but for the future, if you accidentally delete, if you press `CMD` + `Z`, it will undo the delete and return the files to where they were.

Comment: Well... I'll definitely remember for next time! Thnks

Comment: If you mount Trash using `cd ~/.Trash`, does it still show the directory structure preserved if you do `ls`?

Comment: @AMR under `~/.Trash` and `ls` I only see one file (which was deleted from my computer not from the external hard drive). If I copy-paste a file from the trash to the terminal to see the address I see something like `/Volumes/Seagate\ 2TB/.Trashes/501/D31`, where `D31` is one directory I want to put back. I have no idea where the `501` comes from. I can't `cd` to `/Volumes`.

Comment: And sorry I was thinking of my USB flash drive which deletes into `cd ~/.Trash`, not to one in its own directory structure.

Comment: You have to use `sudo` to mount `/Volumes` EDIT and you need to add slash after, so it is `cd Volumes/`.

Comment: There is no need to delete solved questions, the answers will help future visitors as we'll. And you can still uproot/accept answers even if you followed a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works on a **single file** in Trash or multiple files deleted from within the **same directory**:

If it's not essential for you to use Terminal, you can forget all those `bash`, `zsh`, and all other typealot ways to do this. Just navigate to **Trash** and `CMD + Backspace` the files you want to put back.

If the deleted files come from different folders, then you can't use this shortcut to put them all back at the same time.

Comment: Does that work on files from different directories? I tried to delete a few files and I can only use Put Back on all the files if they were from the same directory, otherwise I have to do them individually.

Comment: @AMR It just works. `CMD + BSpace` moves files to **Trash** and from **Trash**.

Comment: Doesn't work if the files are from different directories. Try it out.

Comment: If they are from individual directories, then it only works on individual files, and it sounds like the OP whacked a large portion of his external drive.

Comment: @AMR, Yes, seems to be so. That's why I always delete whole directories :)

Comment: @theoden `CMD + Backspace` seems to be a shortcut for `right-click > Put Back`. It works whenever I select only one item but not when I select multiple items.

Comment: @Remi.b, it works for many files from one directory. But, unfortunately, it was not something you need, I thought it could delete all files to where they were.. By the way, can't you just use `mv`? Or you deleted many files and folders from many folders?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole issue, the files came from several different folders (that were all sister folders). I edited my post to make this point very clear. Thank you!

Comment: @Remi.b, Okay, I gotta sleep. The only problem I see is that when i do `cat .DS_Store` in **Trash** folder it does not recognize the letters as **ascii** (`cat .DS_Store | strings`). If that is accomplished, it's really easy to parse the whole stuff using the list of files in trash in `ls` or `find` and a set of `$FILEkjlfsdhkVolume/.../$FILE;fdjska`.

Comment: @theoden, Where is the command?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei, use `osascript`.